# Required: java tool for creating SOAP requests

Tags: javascript, soap, wsdl

I need to send SOAP requests to some web servicer as part of a systems integration (and catch the responses of course). I am using a systems interfacing product called IMB, that includes wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar.
I had a look at some info on the web about this jar and I get the feeling that it is more suited for creating webservices than for calling them.
What I am looking for is a set of classes that can do roughly the following:
(1) read a WSDL and pre-create lots of SOAP stuff from this (including urls)
(2) provide handlers for providing the remaining stuff, such as the parameter values for a specific method defined in the WSDL.
(3) minimize necessary coding in javascript/groovy
(4) allow catching the response xml content easily or allow for clear error catching

Is wsdl4j suitable for this? Or should it be an Apache SOAP package instead? Maybe another?
Whichever it is, where can I find good clarifying documentation on how to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No answers yet - and I suspect that none will be given in the near future.
Luckily, after some testing I found that IMB offers part of what I needed:
(1) it gets the WSDL from the site and uses this to create the service call accordingly
(2) you only have to provide the XML content; the SOAP envelope and body are pre-created
(3) regular IMB scripting suffices; no javascript or groovy needed
(4) the response is easily caught; error handling I have to add still.

When anyone knows of other tools that do similar, then I am still interested, because IMB is not a freeware tool.